# How to prove that calculating Ackermman function stops?

Tags: induction, recursive-algorithms

Let 
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
A(0,y) &=& y+1 \\
A(x+1,0) &=& A(x,1) \\
A(x+1,y+1) &=& A(x,A(x+1,y))
\end{eqnarray*}$$
be Ackermann function. How to prove by structural induction that calculating $A(n,m)$ for any natural $n,m$ stops?

Comment: Hint: lexicographic ordering.

Comment: See [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: It’s clear that it stops for all $A(0,n)$. Suppose that $m\in\Bbb N$, and it stops for all $A(k,n)$ such that $k\le m$. Show by induction on $n$ that it stops for all $A(m+1,n)$. In other words, you’re doing an induction on the second argument within an induction on the first argument.